# Value set using jquery.data() for newly created node, not accessible in another method - returns undefined!

Tags: jquery

I create a new 'li' in the HTML document and after completing the AJAX request (after sending the form) I wish to add the following data to li like this:

```
<li class="issue" data-winbook-issueId="3">My Issue here</li>
```

I have the reference of the 'li' under question and I try to do the following:

```
liReference.data("winbook-issueId", returnedJSONObject.issueId);
```

If I query this the same in the next line like this:

```
var id = liReference.data("winbook-issueId");
```

I get the value of id in alert or in the Debugger. But if I try and access this data in another function like `deleteIssue()` then id seems to return undefined!!

When the li is initially created there is **no** data attribute. I'm trying to add a new one in the created node (since the 'node' is created using a micro template engine).

Any ideas what I may be missing? I've attached the code below (the above is the conceptual explanation of the code below). I'm trying to access the value "data-winbook-issueId" and "data-winbook-issueStatus"

```
function postDataToWall(contentType, dataAreaToReplaceWithContent)
{
    var content = dataAreaToReplaceWithContent.children('.dataForm').val();
    var postDetailsContainer = dataAreaToReplaceWithContent.parent();
    var wcid = postDetailsContainer.parents('li.listOfIssues').data('winbook-wcid');

    var postData ="Issue="+content+"&wcid="+wcid; 

    $.ajax({

    type:"POST",
    url:"/Issue",
    data:postData,
    success:function(result, status){

    switch(contentType.toLowerCase())
    {
            case "Issue".toLowerCase():
        dataAreaToReplaceWithContent.remove();
    postDetailsContainer.append('<ul class="postDetails">'+
                                                   '<li class="issueid">Issue '+result.issueid+':<li>'+
                                                '<li class="postData">'+content+'</li>'+
                                                '<li><ul class="actionsNavBar">'+
                                                '<li><a class="actionNavBarLink" data-winbook-action="CloseIssue">Close Issue</a><span class="dotSeparator">.</span></li>'+
                                                '<li><a class="actionNavBarLink" data-winbook-action="Comment">Comment</a><span class="dotSeparator">.</span></li>'+
                                                '<li><a class="actionNavBarLink" data-winbook-action="Option">Suggest Option/Alternative(s)</a></li>'+
                                                '</ul></li></ul>');

                    var postNode = postDetailsContainer.parents('li.post');                     
                    postDetailsContainer.parents('.dataForm').toggleClass('dataForm');
                    postNode.children('.hoverMenu').toggle(); //enable the hover menu for delete/edit
                    postNode.data("winbook-issueStatus","open");
                    postNode.data("winbook-issueId",result.issueid);

                    $.data(postNode,"winbook-issueStatus","open");

                    someData = postNode.data("winbook-issueId");
                    someData2 = postNode.data("winbook-issueStatus");                       
                    break;
                    }
                },//end success function

                error: function(xhr, status){
                    alert("Status: "+xhr.status+" = "+xhr.statusText+": "+xhr.responseText);
                }   
            });//end ajax
```

**EDIT**: The function where the data is used:

```
<li class="post issue" data-winbook-issueStatus="open" data-winbook-issueId="44">

                            <a class="delete" data-winbook-delete="issue">

                            <img class="hoverButton deleteButton" src="http://localhost:8080/Winbook/images/deleteredicon.png"/>

                            </a>

                            <a class="edit" data-winbook-edit="issue">

                            <img class="hoverButton editButton" src="http://localhost:8080/Winbook/images/editpencil.png"/>

                            </a>

                            <div class="postContainer">...</li>
```

and it's called in the live('click') handler for a.delete:

```
$('a.delete').live('click', function() {

var issueIdToDelete = $(this).parent().data("winbook-issueId");

//send ajax request for deletion...but issueIdToDelete is undefined!!

}
```

NOTE: The problem is ONLY for the node that I want to delete immediately after creation. Nodes created at the server and sent work fine...The above EDIT snippet is copied from the source file that "shows" the data-* attributes but are not visible in the DOM tree as mentioned in the comments below (and rightly pointed out so by @Pointy)

Comment: Where exactly in that code do things not work?  Are you 100% sure that "postNode" is a non-empty jQuery object?  I'd make sure to check that "postNode.length" is non-zero.

Comment: @Pointy:It doesn't work when I query it in another function. I'm sure postNode is not zero since somedata and somedata2 actually have values in them and the node is infact rendered after this!!! I'll double check though...doing that right now :)

Comment: Well, without seeing this other function, it's going to be pretty hard to see what the problem is. I assure you that the ".data()" mechanism does work.

Comment: Nope. length = 1 .... sigh....

Comment: Okay, so this is weird. When I view the page source the data-winbook-* attributes are there!! But when I'm seeing the DOM view in Chrome it doesn't seem to show up!!

Comment: Setting values via ".data()" does **not** create "data-" attributes on elements.

Comment: @Pointy: have a look at the edit...I've added the code showing where it is being called and how am I doing it. But it's still undefined!!!

Comment: Hmm ... where exactly does the dynamic `<li>` element get the "post" class?  I see "postData" in the first code sample, but not "post". What if the "click" function were changed so that it looks for the `<li>` with `$(this).closest('li.post')` - then you can check to make sure that *that* length is 1 ...

Comment: It is generated by default with that class i.e., "post" since it's a part of the template. What you see in the first sample is a nested child of the the `<li class="post issue">...</li>` I am trying to get the outer li (i.e., the post's id) for deletion

Comment: Okay on further inspection: I checked the server logs and it seems that the DELETE request is indeed being received. But the UI seems to be failing. On Ajax success the following code is called: `function deleteIssue(result, status, issueIdToDelete)
  {
   $('[data-winbook-issueId='+issueIdToDelete+']').fadeOut("slow", function() {
    $(this).remove();
   });
  }` It seems that **this** is the failing point leading us to believe that deletion is indeed not happening! Can the data in the cache be accessed like that?? (since the data is not created but is a part of the cache at that point)

Comment: What template?  I'm looking at the code that adds the `<ul>` block in your first code sample.  Where is class "post" in that code?

Comment: @Pointy: The actual `<li class = "post issue">...</li>` is generated with an internal javascript 'micro template' It helps me use the same code for different data types that I'm working with. It'll just make the post too huge if I were to post that template too! The latter code is actually a snippet of that template...just the data is populated/modified by the first code i.e., `postDataToWall(...)`

Comment: It seems I am facing this problem and am not sure how to fix it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507718/why-dont-changes-to-jquery-fn-data-update-the-corresponding-html-5-data-at

Comment: I do not think that's the case at all.  It is **definitely** possible to access ".data()" values stored on elements from **anywhere** in your code; I have an entire web application that makes extensive use of that. It has nothing to do with "data-" attributes because jQuery keeps the ".data()" stuff in its own global storage facility.

Comment: I think you need to make sure that in the `<a>` event handler, you **explicitly** look for the "li.post" parent object using `.closest('li.post')` and check the ".length" of that result.  It could be that the "click" handler is not finding the `<li>` at all, which would mean that the actual page structure is different than what you think it is.

Comment: @Pointy: Posted the solution :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, thanks to Pointy for being persistent and bearing with me.

It seems that the DOM structure was just fine, what I didn't know was setting the data using the `$.data(key, value)` function only performs the update in the `$.cache` and doesn't create a new data attribute for the DOM node. You can query it alright, but what will fail is the following:

```
$('[data-winbook-issueId='+result.issueId+']').fadeOut("slow",function(){
     $(this).remove();
});
```

Since the data-* attribute that was *just created* as per the ajax call is stored ONLY in the cache. To actually have it be a part of the page DOM for being referenced in this fashion you need to set it using the .attr(...) function like this:

```
postNode.attr("data-winbook-issueId",result.issueId);
```

The explanation for which can be found in the same thread that I had linked to above: [Why don't changes to jQuery $.fn.data() update the corresponding html 5 data-* attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507718/why-dont-changes-to-jquery-fn-data-update-the-corresponding-html-5-data-at)

I tried subscribing to the setData and/or changeData events and use that to update, but for some reason it wasn't working so instead of the added overhead of calling the .attr(...) in the event callback I directly set it on postNode.

Hope that helps someone with the same problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using jQuery 1.6+ ?

In that case you need to access the data camel cased. If your html is:

```
<li data-winbook-issue-id=''>
```

then access it like:

```
liReference.data("winbookIssueId");
```

Comment: Nope. It's 1.5.2 and the above works for existing nodes in the document. Only fails for newly added ones! This one has got me scratching my head for quite a few hours now :)