# Separating & cleaning up tags in data-attribute via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, split, custom-data-attribute

I have a list of items which will contain a tag using the `data-type` attribute. I'm attempting to loop through the items to grab each tag in an array. Where a list item has more than one tag (separated by a comma) I want to split the tags and clean up any white-space.

**Here is my HTML:**

```
<div class="article-wrap">
  <ul class="articles">
    <li sata-type="tag3"> <a href="#">LTE opens vast new business and revenue opportunities. Here's how to get ready.</a>

    </li>
    <li data-type="tag3"> <a href="#">Bringing NFC into the Digital Home</a>

    </li>
    <li data-type="tag3, tag4"> <a href="#">Keep Up with Rapidly-changing Wi-Fi Standards, Techniques and Markets</a>

    </li>
    <li data-type="tag1"> <a href="#">Technicolor Professional Services help NSPs reduce software vulnerability</a>

    </li>
    <li data-type="tag2, tag3"> <a href="#">Our New Satellite/terrestrial HD Set-top Box Provides a Smooth Path to HDTV.</a>

    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**And here is my JS:**

```
$(function () {
    var items = $('.article-wrap li'),
        itemsByTags = {};

    // Looping though all the li items:
    items.each(function (i) {
        var elem = $(this),
            tags = elem.data('type').split(',');

        // Adding a data-id attribute
        elem.attr('data-id', i);

        $.each(tags, function (key, value) {
            // Removing extra whitespace:
            value = $.trim(value);

            if (!(value in itemsByTags)) {
                // Create an empty array to hold this item:
                itemsByTags[value] = [];
            }

            // Each item is added to one array per tag:
            itemsByTags[value].push(elem);
        });

    });
});
```

I believe this should be working fine, alas I get **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'split' of undefined**. You can see this here: http://jsfiddle.net/94UUF/2/

I can use the same `items` var to amend CSS etc but the `.split` function doesn't seem to want to play ball. Please advise!

Comment: I wouldn't comma-separate your `data-type`s. Separate with whitespace instead, since that's normal for classes anyway.

Comment: `<li sata-type="tag3">` is this typo just in the example? Would explain the error...

Comment: For that matter, if you used classes instead of `data-` attributes, you could just use jQuery selectors instead of parsing the `data` yourself.

Comment: For the data-id attribute which you are trying to add: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6827810/unable-to-set-data-attribute-using-jquery-data-api

Comment: @Blazemonger thanks for the suggestion. What is the benefit of sticking with classes? I'm using data attributes so that I can separate the content from my styling references, as I'm using a number of plugins on the list item (a LiveSearch & Quicksand for sorting)

Comment: With classes, you could obtain an array of matching elements with `$('.article-wrap li.tag3').get()`. I don't consider this an inappropriate use of classes since (a) you can add as many classes as you like and (b) you're not storing actual data as a class, just an arbitrary name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you notice:

```
<li sata-type="tag3">
```

Is `sata` instead of `data` hence the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'split' of undefined.
```

Comment: Oh wow. I totally missed that! That's a bit of type-o! I've that in the JSFiddle and that appears to fix the problem. However in my local (larger) file the issue still exists. From what I can see I am always referencing `data-type`, is there anything else that can cause the same issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can actually embed object literals in data tags. So if you do `data-type='["tag3”, ”tag4”]'` then `.data('type')` will return an array.