# Data attribute value can't be updated

Tags: jquery, attributes

I want to update the value of data attribute. I checked showing alert message but when I inspect element the value is not updated. Here is my code:

```
     alert(pid); // show 1
     alert($('#buybtn').data('id')); // show 'hello'
     $('#buybtn').data('id',pid);
     alert($('#buybtn').data('id')); // show 1
```

But after this code run I checked the data attribute value. It shows previous data as follows:
[image]

What is the wrong in my code? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Nothing is wrong with the code - see answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6827810/unable-to-set-data-attribute-using-jquery-data-api/6828180#6828180 and others

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery's data attribute does not update the visible HTML markup - it only updates an internal copy of the data.  This performs better and works perfectly as long as you always use `jQuery.data()` to access/change.

Otherwise, use `jQuery.attr('data-id', pid)`

not recommended:

```
$('#buybtn').attr('data-id', pid)
```

Comment: forgot to add the reference - https://api.jquery.com/data/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6827810/unable-to-set-data-attribute-using-jquery-data-api/6828180#6828180

Answer (score 0):

I found a tricks to solve this. As data attribute can't be updated I removed that and add with update value.

```
 $('#buybtn').attr('data-id');
     $('#buybtn').attr('data-id',pid);

     alert($('#buybtn').data('id'));
```

Comment: CAUTION: This may only work once: the **first** time a `.data()` function is used, jQuery loads all data attributes into its own internal data structures.

Comment: But it works for me to over write several times. I tested