# Jquery on hover adding data id and with another on hover geting the data id but it is only getting the first id

Tags: javascript, jquery

In first hover i am getting data id from thumbs and adding to #main image it is working fine and with 2nd hover on #main i am getting the data id again here from the first data id. but it is only getting the 1 data id not another ids when i am changing it on first hover.

```
<div class="gry">
    <img id="main" src="images/1.jpg" alt="alt" data-id="1" />
    <img id="sm001" src="images/1.jpg" alt="alt" data-id="1" />
    <img id="sm002" src="images/2.jpg" alt="alt" data-id="2" />
    <img id="sm003" src="images/3.jpg" alt="alt" data-id="3" />
    <img id="sm004" src="images/4.jpg" alt="alt" data-id="4" />
</div>
```

```
$('img[id^=sm00]').hover(function() {
  $('#main').attr({src:$(this).data('img'), alt:$(this).attr('alt'), "data-id":$(this).attr('data-id')});
});

$('#main').hover(function() {
    var form_data = new FormData();
    form_data.append('action', 'view-img');
    form_data.append('id', $(this).data('id'));
    alert($(this).data('id'));
    $.ajax({
        url: 'load.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        data: form_data,
        type: 'post',
        success: function (response) {
            var code = response.code;
            $( ".gry" ).append( "<img id='vimg' />" );
            $('#vimg').attr('src', code);
        }
    });
},function () {
    $("#vimg").remove();
});
```

Comment: `$(..).attr("data-id", val)` won't be returned when you do `$(..).data("id")` - jquery keeps .data cached, it doesn't read the `data-id` attribute each time.  Read *and set* data via matching `$(..).data("id", newvalue)` / `$(..).data("id")`

Comment: show your html structure as well

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to set data attribute using jQuery Data() API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6827810/unable-to-set-data-attribute-using-jquery-data-api)

Comment: thank you all for your help, can you edit full code or can explain? freedomn-m

Comment: do `console.log(response.code)` and see what it has ? Also try to change `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` to `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" ></script>`

Comment: update your code Swati

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just fixed the issue i just take the data id in input value it working fine now :)