# Data-value updates in DOM, but not in function

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I alter the text of a button based on the selection by the user.

```
$(".someClass").click(function() {
    $("#someID_1").text($(this).prop("innerHTML"));
    $("#someID_1").attr("data-value", $(this).data("value"));

    someFunction("someID_1");
});
```

I then want to call a function `someFunction`.

```
function someFunction(someID) {
    console.log(parseInt($("#" + someID).data("value")))
    if ( parseInt($("#" + someID).data("value")) !== 10 ) {
        // do something
    } else {
        // do something else
    }
}
```

Whats happening is that `console.log` plots on the very first function call (thus, very first click) the `data-value` of the selection. However, when I select something new and the function gets executed again, the `data-value` plotted through the `console.log` stays the same. Looking at the `DOM`, the `data-value` gets updated though.

Why is that?

Comment: Take care of your `parseInt` you must specify your base : `parseInt($("#" + someID).data("value"), 10)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `.data()` uses internal cache it only uses uses the data attribute as the default value only and updating the attribute don't impact it,

You need to use `.data(key, value)` to set value. If you need to update DOM then use `.attr()`

```
$("#someID_1").data("value", $(this).data("value"));
```

---

If you use `attr()` to get and set, you will get the updated value. What you **shouldn't** use, is a mix of `attr()` and `data()`. And if you have no real reason to update the attribute, then use `data()` to get and set value.

Comment: The `data-value` gets updated. I can see it in my `DOM`

Comment: and btw. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22868080/jquery-data-value-not-updating

Comment: @Stophface, `.data()` uses attribute value only for default value, if you update attribute then its never used

Comment: So if I want to update the `DOM` I need to use `attr()`. Because in the `DOM` I see that the `data-value` is updated. But, when I want to "really" (?) update the `data-value` I need to use `data.(key, value)`?

Comment: unfortunately that does not update the `data-value` neither. It remains in its "start-value" which would be "0".

Comment: @Stophface If you want to update the attribute, use in jQuery `attr()` to get and set. Now to add more confusion, to really update the data attribute and object, you should use: [dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset). To set: `$("#someID_1")[0].dataset.value = 666;` and to get: `$("#someID_1")[0].dataset.value` and forgive about jQuery `$.fn.data` which as you can see can be quite confusing. You can compare regarding quite unexpected result between [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wahbra4c/) and [this one](https://jsfiddle.net/wahbra4c/1/)

Comment: @A.Wolff, I forgot about `dataset`, You should post that as an answer

Comment: @Satpal In fact, i would suggest OP to use `attr()` if his goal is to update attribute, e.g, regarding some CSS rules.  DOM node `dataset` would just add more confusion in any production code imho.

Comment: @A.Wolff the problem with `attr()` is that I only receive the updated value *once*. When I update it again, it stays the same.

Comment: @Stophface `When I update it again, it stays the same` If you use `attr()` to get and set, no, you will get the updated value. What you **shouldn't** use, is a mix of `attr()` and `data()`. And if you have no real reason to update the attribute, then use `data()` to get and set value. What is preferred method really depends of your real use case

Comment: @Stophface, That should not be the case, If you are setting using `$("#someID_1").attr("data-value", $(this).data("value"));` then use `$("#someID_1").attr("data-value");` to fetch it

Comment: @A.Wolff Here we go. I mixed the two methods. Having three methods is rather confusing, however, I can imagine when you want to mix `data()` and `attr()`. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Satpal you might want to include the comment from you in your answere

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
$(document).on('click', ".someClass", function()
   {
       //your event logic
   }
```